# React Native: print full image in a Scrollview

Tags: react-native

I have an image that is very tall, but not very large. I want to print it in a scrollview, so you can see it all on one screen, but nothing works.

after playing with widths and heights and flexs for my scrollview and my image, the best result I get is when I have on of them with style={{width='100%'}}, like that

```
<ScrollView style={{width: '100%'}}>
    <Image
      source={require('./assets/skeleton/fullSkeleton.png')}
      resizeMode='cover'
      />
  </ScrollView>
```

which prints the image at full width, but the scrollview's height is the original image's height, which doesn't let me see the whole resized image.

Here, a bad drawing to represent my image, and what I want to see on my phone screen
[image: shitty drawing to make it clearer]

EDIT:
With this bit of code:

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Image
      source={require('./fullSkeleton.png')}
      resizeMode='cover'
      />
</ScrollView>
```

I end up with

[image]

Which can be scrolled down to see the rest of the Image. As you can see, it can be navigated vertically, but doesn't take the whole screen's width

Comment: I'm confused - are you trying to make the image appear in a *single* screen, as in resized, OR trying to put it in a scroll-view so that it can be scrolled through?

Comment: i added a drawgin, to represent the image i have, and what i want on my phoone screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following may help:

You can use contentContainerStyle to style the contents of the ScrollView. Like this (essentially what you have):

```
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Image
      source={require('./fullSkeleton.png')}
      resizeMode='cover'
      />
</ScrollView>
```

That works for me - I can scroll down the whole image and at the bottom it stays visible.

NB: To make the image cover the whole screen while maintaining the height required, you will need to set the width specifically. In my case on iPhone 7+ that meant adding style={{width: 414}} to the Image component AND changing resizeMode to 'stretch'.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#why-not-automatically-size-everything) is the official take on Image resizing...and [getting device dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) will be useful here too.

Comment: Ok, but the behaviour you show in the diagram is what you get using the ScrollView code in my answer. The only thing I can think of that you might mean is not as you want it is if you want more space at the bottom of the image. If so, just wrap the image in a view and style it with paddingBottom to the amount of extra size you want...that should do it.

Comment: I just got back to my pc, so I tested the first part of your answer. It would seem to be ok, but it doesn't take the whole width of the screen: the image can be navigated vertically in, just as I wanted, but it doesn't take the whole width :/
I edited my question to give you a more visual example.

Comment: a have same issue, do you have solution ? :(

Comment: not working for me.. showing a blank page. after 2 years working with RN i fed up.. really. such a small little requirement and wasting so much time on it.. really prefer to go native and develop smoothly 2 time.. sorry for the frustration, needed to get it out.. so annoyed by this

Answer (score 8):

This kind of thing in Reat Native is actually quite tricky. But you can do it easily; First get picture dimensions:

```
const FullWidthPicture = ({ uri }) => {
  const [ratio, setRatio] = useState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (uri) {
      Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
         setRatio(width / height);
      });
   }
  }, [uri]);

  return (
   <Image
     style={{ width: '100%', height: undefined, aspectRatio: ratio }}
     resizeMode="contain"
     source={{ uri }}
   />
 );
};
```

And use it like this:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
  <FulWidthImage uri={pictureUri} />
</ScrollView>
```